# How does managed metadata navigation create a webpart in the quick launch side bar?

Tags: quick-launch

I was admiring the managed metadata navigation. When you select a list, a webpart automatically appears in the quick launch side bar. This can be used for filtering list items.

When you select another site element, the web part is no longer visible.

Is this difficult to do? Basically attach a web part to the quick launch and detach it, when the list loads or unloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, all these functions could be implemented with no problems.

Though, I recommend you to use not a webpart, but a user control, and attach it to your pages using [Delegate Control](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/06/using-delegate-control.html) approach.

Inside your control, you can check [Request.RawUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx) or enumerate webparts on the page using [SPLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.aspx), or whatever.. - to determine, if the control contents need to be shown. Based on that knowledge, you can finally setup `Visible` properties of inner controls.